# Why my NAN is replacing in numpy.genfromtext()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Numpy
python
filling missing values
here is my mode is anybody can tell where is the problem here ?

```py
  import numpy as np
  lending_co_missing_values = np.genfromtxt('missing_dataset.csv', delimiter=',')
  lending_co_missing_values
  array([[ 2000.,    40.,   365.,  3121.,  4241., 13621.],
       [ 2000.,    40.,   365.,  3061.,  4171., 15041.],
       [ 1000.,    40.,   365.,  2160.,  3280., 15340.],
       ...,
       [   nan,    40.,   365.,  4201.,  5001., 16600.],
       [ 1000.,    40.,   365.,  2080.,  3320., 15600.],
       [ 2000.,    40.,   365.,  4601.,  4601., 16600.]])
       temporary_fill = np.nanmax(lending_co_missing_values).round(2)+1
       temporary_fill
       64002.0
       lending_co_missing_values = np.genfromtxt("missing_dataset.csv", delimiter = ',', filling_values = temporary_fill )
       lending_co_missing_values
       array([[ 2000.,    40.,   365.,  3121.,  4241., 13621.],
       [ 2000.,    40.,   365.,  3061.,  4171., 15041.],
       [ 1000.,    40.,   365.,  2160.,  3280., 15340.],
       ...,
       [   nan,    40.,   365.,  4201.,  5001., 16600.],
       [ 1000.,    40.,   365.,  2080.,  3320., 15600.],
       [ 2000.,    40.,   365.,  4601.,  4601., 16600.]])
```

please notice nan is not replaced.

Comment: Please post code as text, not a link to an image of text.

Comment: What do you *want* to happen to "missing values"?

Comment: i have pasted the code now

Comment: i want to fill it with the maximum value of its dataset.